# Button is not destroyed when class is deinstantiated

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection, p5.js

I'm using P5.js to create two scenes

A global variable `currentScene` instantiates the Scene to be rendered.

Then I have two scene classes:

- A MainMenuScene, with a button New Game that instantiates CombatScene
- A CombatScene where I will render my game.

Now, the button New Game is creates inside the class MainMenu, so when currentScene no longer points to MainMenuScene, I'd expect the instance to be garbage collected, and since the button is an attribute of the class, I'd expect it to also be garbage collected.

However, it looks like although the scene correctly changes to CombatScene (red background) the button remains there.

Why does it remain there, and how can I get rid of it?

Does the button "surviving" mean that it's preventing the MainMenu instance from being garbage collected?

```
class MainMenuScene {
  constructor() {

    // button is an attribute of the class, 
    //so when the instance of theclass is garbage collected 
    // it should disappear, but it doesn't
    this.button = createButton("New Game");
    this.button.position(100, 100);
    this.button.mousePressed(() => {

      // here currentScene changes to CombatScene, so the instance of
      // MainMenuScene should be garbage collected, right?
      currentScene = new CombatScene();
    });
  }
  show() {
    background("blue");
  }
}

class CombatScene {
  constructor() {}
  show() {
    background("red");
  }
}

let currentScene;


function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  currentScene = new MainMenuScene();
}

function draw() {
  currentScene.show();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In p5.js there is a remove() method which removes the button from canvas. You can use this method for your solution.

```
class MainMenuScene {
      constructor() {
    
        // button is an attribute of the class, 
        //so when the instance of theclass is garbage collected 
        // it should disappear, but it doesn't
        this.button = createButton("New Game");
        this.button.position(100, 100);
        this.button.mousePressed(() => {
    
          // here currentScene changes to CombatScene, so the instance of
          // MainMenuScene should be garbage collected, right?
          currentScene = new CombatScene();
          this.button.remove(); // removes the button after scene is switched
        });
      }
      show() {
        background("blue");
      }
    }
    
    class CombatScene {
      constructor() {}
      show() {
        background("red");
      }
    }
    
    let currentScene;
    
    
    function setup() {
      createCanvas(400, 400);
      currentScene = new MainMenuScene();
    }
    
    function draw() {
      currentScene.show();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. I'll wait a bit before accepting your answer, since I'd like to know why it's not being garbage collected, and know if the button is then preventing the instance of MainMenu from being garbage collected.

Comment: @Elerium115 Because there's still an object on the page that could possibly be queried and removed. The behavior by design is that JS doesn't assume that because a JS variable goes out of scope, that it should remove the corresponding HTML element from the page. Many HTML elements don't have a corresponding JS object, yet they still work and hold internal state and memory.

Comment: But the button is not a global variable, but an attribute of a class instance that is no longer referenced. My understanding is that when an instance is no longer referenced, their attributes are also no longer referenced, so the whole instance will be garbage collected.

Comment: It doesn't make a difference whether the variable is inside an object or not: JS simply does not destroy HTML elements unless you ask it to explicitly, under any circumstance that I've seen. It's common for JS code to create element objects that are added to the page, then go out of scope, leaving the elements on the page behind. BTW, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75331195/6243352) which shows state cleanup.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Coming from other languages it was strange to me that this attribute was not automatically garbage collected. I'll use `remove` as suggested in the answer.

Comment: @Elerium115 The JS variable _is_ garbage collected, but the attached HTML element isn't. The flow is like: (1) create JS object (2) use the JS object to manipulate the page to create a new HTML element that it points to (3) remove the JS object, leaving the HTML element behind. Later, you could re-query the HTML element and manipulate it further using a new JS DOM object that points to the same HTML element. All HTML elements are in the DOM tree, so they're always accessible/referenced ("Many HTML elements don't have a corresponding JS object" I stated earlier isn't exactly accurate).