# How to switch from a menu screen to actual game?

Tags: javascript, loops, class, menu, p5.js

So I am trying to switch between a menu screen (currently just a blank canvas with a line of text) and the actual game screen in p5.js. What I have tried at the moment is using a variable called 'state' which branches between the code for the menu and the code for the actual game depending on its value ( state = 1 for menu and state = 2 for game). When state changes from 1 to 2, it does switch to the game screen, but it is just a still frame and is unplayable.

As I said above, I have tried branching between the different game states with a variable called 'state'. The code I have written is below, excluding the classes.

```
  var state;
  var character;
  var platform;

  function setup() {
    state = 1;
    createCanvas(800, 400);
  }

  function draw() {
    background(220);
    if(state == 1){
      text("press enter to start",20,20);
    }
    else if(state == 2){
      enemy = new Enemy(50, 0)
      character = new Player(200, 200);
      platform = new Platform(0, 350, width, 50);
      
      character.update();
      platform.update();
      enemy.update();

      enemy.show();
      character.show();
      platform.show();
    }
    if (keyIsDown(UP_ARROW)) 
    {
      if (!character.jumping && character.grounded) {
        character.jumping = true;
        character.grounded = false;
        character.velY = -character.speed * 3;
      }
    }
    if (keyIsDown(LEFT_ARROW)) {
      character.velX = -character.speed;
    }
    if (keyIsDown(RIGHT_ARROW)) {
      character.velX = character.speed;
    }
  }
  
  function keyPressed(){
  if(keyCode === ENTER)
    state = 2
  }
```

I believe the issue is that every time the draw loop repeats, it creates a new instance of all the classes making the game appear like a still frame as the objects are replaced with each loop. Although I think that is the issue, I don't know how to fix it. Any help would be appreciated not just specific to this issue but my code in general.

[Image of still frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4c6P.png)
ps. this image shows what the still frame looks like. There is 'gravity' so both squares should be falling.

Answer (score 1):

The branches that switch based on the scene number in the `draw()` function should only be updating and drawing, not initializing state for that scene. Only the code that transitions from the menu to the game screen should be creating game-related entities. Otherwise, you create a new `Enemy`, `Player` and `Platform` ~60 times a second, always in their initial positions, so they appear immobile.

In other words, move assignments like `enemy =` into the `if(keyCode === ENTER)` branch, which should be thought of as a game scene-specific `setup()` function (and, optionally, menu scene teardown).

See also [Transitioning from one scene to the next with p5.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58477636/transitioning-from-one-scene-to-the-next-with-p5-js/71959307#71959307) which shows a more robust design that handles many scenes with complex transitions, each with specific input and rendering behaviors. The approach in that answer also adds closures around each scene's variables, making it easier to keep state from accidentally leaking from one scene to another.

Short of that, `1` and `2` are magic numbers, and could be improved to be at least descriptive strings or symbols, or maybe a boolean `let menuActive = true; // or false`. Or you could replace the `draw()` function with the gameplay version of `draw()` and remove branching:

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(800, 400);
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  text("press enter to start", 20, 20);
}

function gameLoop(t) {
  background(150);
  text("you're in the game loop!", sin(frameCount / 2) + 10, 20);
}

function initializeGameLoop() {
  // one-time set up gameLoop here
  print("switching scenes");
  draw = gameLoop;
}

function keyPressed() {
                        // you can check which state you're in like this,
                        // or alternatively, override/redefine keyPressed
                        // the same way as done with draw()
                        // v---------------v
  if (keyCode === ENTER && draw !== gameLoop) {
    /* optionally tear down state for the menu screen here */

    initializeGameLoop();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.7.0/p5.js"></script>
```

This approach has less state, fewer magic numbers and fewer branches, all of which add complexity to programs, making them harder to understand and maintain.